# Which information is shared when checking "Trust this device" on a login form?

Tags: authentication, web, multi-factor-authentication

I'm seeing more and more MFA logins showing the checkbox "Always trust this device", so that I don't have to receive a code (example via SMS) the next time I login from the same client.

Which data is shared and stored from the client to the server to enable this?